# Where are build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, build.gradle

After I upgraded to AS 4.2 and started receiving the message that AndroidManifest.xml is missing.
Then I realized that there was no AndroidManifest.xml file in the project tree. And also, build.gradle was not in the tree.
I clean installed 4.2 and previous versions 4.1, and 3.6. Same result.
I never had to create myself AndroidManifest.xml. What is happening? I just can't use Android Studio anymore. Even a recently created flutter project comes with one of the following errors:

- AndroidManifest.xml is missing
- Your Flutter application is created using older version of the Android embedding (even a recently created project in which I have done nothing to change).

[image: Android project tree]

Answer (score 0):

Can you see that Drop-down menu where Project is written click it and make it Android.I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to 4.2.1 and see if it fixes Manifest issues.

Also check android gradle plugin version. Upgrade/downgrade to see if it helps.
Any error messages/Logs

Comment: Thanks, ntippa.
I was already using 4.2.1 (sorry for saying just '4.2'). Anyway, I reinstalled it and now, all files appear.
AS is somewhat troublesome.